# How to create a dataset with google cloud AutoML

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-automl

Silly question, but I'm new to Python and Google Cloud. I'm trying to predict customer-lifetime-value with google cloud automl_v1beta1, the code is here

```
  from google.cloud.automl_v1beta1 import AutoMlClient, PredictionServiceClient
  from google.cloud_v1beta1 import automl

  client = AutoMlClient.from_service_account_file(keyfile_name)
  location_path = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/us-central1"
  dataset_display_name = automl_dataset
  # create dataset
  create_dataset_response = client.create_dataset(
      parent=location_path,
      dataset={'display_name': dataset_display_name, 'tables_dataset_metadata': {}})
```

and I received the following errors:
\

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  

File "/home/tensorflow-lifetime-value/clv_automl/test1.py", line 220, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/tensorflow-lifetime-value/clv_automl/test1.py", line 193, in main
    model_name = create_automl_model(client,
  File "/home/tensorflow-lifetime-value/clv_automl/test1.py", line 48, in 

create_automl_model
    create_dataset_response = client.create_dataset(
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/automl_v1/services/auto_ml/client.py", line 623, in create_dataset
    request.dataset = dataset
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/message.py", line 757, in __setattr__
    pb_value = marshal.to_proto(pb_type, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 211, in to_proto
    pb_value = rule.to_proto(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/rules/message.py", line 36, in to_proto
    return self._descriptor(**value)
ValueError: Protocol message Dataset has no "tables_dataset_metadata" field.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error using your code when I used `google-cloud-automl<=0.1.2`. Your error will be fixed if you use `google-cloud-automl>=0.1.2`. But I suggest to always install the latest version by doing `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-automl` to maximize the latest updates from Google Cloud.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience, quite a big difference between google cloud versions

Comment: @tinywhale69 if this helped you resolve the issue, you can accept the answer so the question will be marked as solved. [See What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)